# How animate css3 with div content together?

Tags: css

I made a animation and here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KCbFf/4/).
But the contents won't animate with the div together, any suggestions?
HTML

```
<div id="fdiv" align="center">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #fdiv{
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .go{
            -webkit-animation: spinAndZoom 1s 1;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spinAndZoom {
            0% {
                width: 10px; 
                height: 10px; 
                margin-left: -5px;
                margin-top: -5px;
                -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            }
            100% {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                margin-left: -200px;
                margin-top: -200px;
                -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            }
        }
```

JS

```
$(function(){
        $("#fdiv").delay(1000).addClass("go");
    });
```

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to your #fdiv CSS to keep child text within the bounding box.

Comment: @nich content in div is also animating.

Comment: It seems to work okay in Chrome, what seems to be missing?

Comment: I guessed his question is related to the size of the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With not animating you mean the size of the content? Then add `font-size` to your animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinAndZoom {
    0% {
        width: 10px; 
        height: 10px; 
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        font-size: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-left: -200px;
        margin-top: -200px;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

As shennan mentioned, the animation of font-size is most of the time a bit jerky. 
I've added `ease-in` to the animation, to make it appear less jerky at the end.

```
.go {
    -webkit-animation: spinAndZoom 1s 1 ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCbFf/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Kilian's suggestion by adding `font-size` to the webkit animation, but the results are a little jerky.

I would either use a dynamically created image/canvas to create the text, or simply call your losses and add `overflow:hidden` to the `#fdiv` CSS block to get rid of the initial text spilling over the edge of your div:

```
#fdiv{

    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow:hidden; /* here is your eureka fix */

}
```